Spring Boot & Next.js: 'Full Authentication is Required' Error Despite Adding Bearer Token
I have a Spring Boot backend and a Next.js frontend using the Refine framework. While my API works perfectly in Postman and Swagger (including authentication-protected endpoints), I'm encountering an issue in the application where only the /login and /register endpoints work. For other endpoints, I receive the error:

Full Authentication is required to access this resource

What I've Tried:

Bearer Token: I'm adding the Bearer token to the Authorization header for requests.

getList: async ({ resource, pagination, sorters, filters, meta }) => {
    const auth = Cookies.get("auth");
    const token = auth ? JSON.parse(auth)?.accessToken.toString() : null;
    const { current, pageSize } = pagination ?? {};

    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/${resource}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
        },
      }).then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      const total = data?.length;

      return {
        data,
        total,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Fetch error:", error);
      throw error; // Re-throw the error after logging it
    }
},


Spring Security Configuration: My Spring Boot application has a security configuration where the /login and /register endpoints are public, and all other endpoints require authentication.

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
        .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.antMatchers("/api/users/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll() // allow swagger
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll() // allow swagger
            .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll() // internal swagger urls
            .anyRequest().authenticated());

    http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}


CORS Configuration: I've configured CORS to allow requests from my frontend:

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTION").allowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        //enabling swagger-ui part for visual documentation
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/","swagger-ui.html" );
    }
}


You can check the backend: GitHub
You can check the frontend: GitHub

Despite these configurations, when I make requests to the secured endpoints from my Next.js app, the backend responds with "Full Authentication is required to access this resource."
Everything works as expected in Postman and Swagger, so I'm not sure where the disconnect is between the frontend app and the backend.What might be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to ensure authenticated requests from my frontend are properly recognized by the backend?

Backend Error
Frontend Error 1
Frontend Error 2

I've reviewed similar questions on Stack Overflow but have not found a solution.
Thank you for your help!

The solution to your issue probably resides in the "authenticationProvider" and "authenticationJwtTokenFilter". For anyone to assist you effectively, you would need to provide those details here.

It looks like the issue might be related to CORS configuration, especially if the secured endpoints work in Postman but not in the frontend.
I encountered a similar issue before, and I solved it by explicitly adding CORS configuration in the security filter chain. This allows the frontend to make authenticated requests with credentials.
Here’s an example of how you can configure it in your SecurityFilterChain:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))  // Enable CORS with custom configuration
        .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000"));  // Set your frontend's origin
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Content-Type"));
    corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);  // Allow credentials (needed if you’re sending cookies or tokens)

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
    return source;
}

Also, on the frontend side, make sure that you are sending credentials (like tokens) properly. When using fetch, you need to include the credentials: "include" option if you're handling cookies for authentication:
fetch(`${API_URL}/${resource}`, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
  },
  credentials: "include",  // Include credentials in the request
});

Click here for another solution
